# Make form input field take up all the width in a div that isn't occupied by other elements

Tags: html, css

I have a centered `div` that contains a header, input, and button in a row.  I would like to make the input field expand so that the total width of the contents of the `div` take up the entire width allotted to the `div`.  Is there some CSS way to specify something like `width: 100%-other_elems`?

Comment: share your code.

Comment: You can use width:calc(100% - other_elems).. Where other_elems will be the width of other elemets in px .

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some CSS way to specify something like width: 100%-other_elems?

Yes using [`flex-box`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Flexbox part of the browser's layout engine to create dynamic and flexible boxes or divs. See the example below and try resizing. Refer to CSS trick's [flexbox tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for a complete rundown of flexbox. It's a fantastic reference that I use it all the time.

CSS rundown:

- `display: flex` on `.some-container` declares that any element with the class `some-container` will use flexbox.
- `flex: 1` on `.expand` declares that in the parent flexbox (i.e. `some-container`) this element should *grow*.

```css
.some-container { display: flex; }

.expand { flex: 1; }
```

```html
<div class="some-container">
  <h1>some header</h1>
  <input class="expand" type="text">
  <button>some button</button>
</div>
```